# dropdownlist.Text not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

dropdownlist always show the first index of Item populated from database and in debug mode `ddlcountry.Text` always empty string`("")`.
I have "Philippines" item in my dropdownlist but "Argentina" always shown first in my dropdown instead of "Philippines". 
Please help.

```
//in formload
     if(!isPostback)
        {
                    DataTable dtCountry= new DataTable();
                    dtCountry= network.GetCountry();
                    for (int row = 0; row < dtCountry.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        ddlCoutry.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = dtCountry.Rows[row][1].ToString(), Value = dtCountry.Rows[row][1].ToString() });

                    }
        }

ddlCountry.Text = "Philippines";
```

Comment: in form load I want to view info of a person

Comment: Can you post a block of code, including how you are binding your dropdown? how you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: Are you trying to add Philippines after your datalist is bound?

Comment: No there is already Philippines in the Item.I want Philippines to be the selected text

Comment: `ddlCountry.Text = "Philippines";` this piece of code means in your existing dropdown you are trying to select the option which has Philippines as `Value` not text. For text you should use `ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text = "Philippines";`

Comment: @RahulSingh that doesn't work that will set the text on the top, but not at the correct index. He'll see Philipines twices

Comment: @prospector - Yup got it!

Comment: @awtszs- Did your problem got resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above, I think your problem is you are trying to select the dropdown option by text but getting confused with `.Text` property. You can do this:-

```
ddlCountries.Items.FindByText("Philippines").Selected = true;
```

Comment: I follow your comment. `ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text = "Philippines";` thanks I will accept your answer

Comment: @awtszs - But that will duplicate the option, so use whatever I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: yes it duplicate the option so i use `Items.Remove`

Answer (score 1):

Set the selected item to "Philippines" because I assume your list of countries is in alphabetical order.

```
ddlCountry.SelectedIndex = ddlCountry.Items.IndexOf(ddlCountry.Items.FindByText("Philippines"));
```

Also I want to point out your variable is misspelled:

```
**ddlCoutry**.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = dtCountry.Rows[row][1].ToString(), Value = dtCountry.Rows[row][1].ToString() });
```